# Which are the new notifications in Android app?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, notifications, android-app

Clicking on notification counter icon, it lists out all the notification messages but there is no clear indication which are the new/unread messages among all the notifications?

All the new/unread notifications should be in different font color or have different background than the font color/background of read questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed as of version 0.1.36 coming out later today.

[image]

Comment: Off Topic, but what app(?) is that sidebar?

Comment: It's the Genymotion emulator, not a real device.